# How to get rid of key error: " " in a python programming?

Tags: python

The following is a program to count only words in a string of sentence-

```
def count_letters(text):
  result = {}
  # Go through each letter in the text
  for letter in text.lower():
    # Check if the letter needs to be counted or not
    if letter.isalpha():
        if letter not in result:
          result[letter]=0
    # Add or increment the value in the dictionary
    result[letter]+=1
  return result
```

Every time I am getting this error-

```
Error on line 10:
    result[letter]+=1
KeyError: ' '
```

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect that you meant to indent that line one more step.

Comment: It perfectly works for me! which text did you try?

Comment: Indent this: `result[letter]+=1`.

Comment: Yes, actually later I found out that  result[letter]+=1 is running not under the conditions so I fixed that

Answer (score 2):

You're only initializing the `result` dict for `isalpha` characters, yet incrementing it for everything:

```
def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text.lower():
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter not in result:
                result[letter] = 0
        result[letter] += 1  # <-- this occurs whether or not `isalpha` is true
    return result
```

The simple fix is

```
def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text.lower():
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter not in result:
                result[letter] = 0
            result[letter] += 1
    return result
```

and we can further improve this by using `.get()` to initialize the dict key as we go:

```
def count_letters(text):
    result = {}
    for letter in text.lower():
        if letter.isalpha():
            result[letter] = result.get(letter, 0) + 1
    return result
```

We can still do better with some library methods; `collections.Counter`s automagically initialize entries to zero and otherwise act like dicts (with some additional methods):

```
import collections


def count_letters(text):
    result = collections.Counter()
    for letter in text.lower():
        if letter.isalpha():
            result[letter] += 1
    return result
```

... and finally we can do even better with a list comprehension since `Counter`s can be initialized from sequences:

```
import collections

def count_letters(text):
    return collections.Counter(
        [
            letter
            for letter in text.lower()
            if letter.isalpha()
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer!
Here is the modified code:

```
    def count_letters(text):
      result = {}
      # Go through each letter in the text
      for letter in text.lower():
        # Check if the letter needs to be counted or not
        if letter.isalpha():
            if letter not in result:
              result[letter]=0
        # Add or increment the value in the dictionary
        if letter in result:
           result[letter]+=1

  return result
```